# Are all these duct taping on my furnace normal?

Tags: furnace, ventilation

I just bought the house, and I saw these duct tapes on my furnace in the basement (I guess it's not exactly a furnace, but also an air ventilation system since it's turning on in summer). Now what are all these duct taping? is this normal, also should I retape them since they have mostly came loose, and cold air is blowing out of the holes.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This is a combined furnace/refrigeration air handler. Presumably the air coming out of the ducts is cool right now, about 60 F or so.  And presumably you have a functioning outside "condensing unit". Do you have that? Where is this property located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfectly normal sealing of penetrations by wires. Looks like a first rate installation.

BTW you have a tee fitting on the condensate line which is well placed to allow cleaning of the line to clear it of algae or wet dust. Many pretty good installations do not have this feature (mine doesn't). It seems to me that you should gently insert a rubber stopper in the open end. This would prevent something falling in and would reduce leakage of air out the condensate drain. At the very least put a loose cover over it to prevent something falling in.

Comment: Good to know, personally I thought it looks ghetto as hell lol. So should I re-tape the duct tapes that have came loose?

Comment: Why does a heater have water pipes and a water drain?

Comment: That is FAR from a "first rate install". It DOES look ghetto as hell, and very unprofessional. "Duct tape" IS NOT for ducts. At least the silver/colored fabric stuff. Tape for ducts is foil and has a peel and stick backing. It's generically called, unsurprisingly, foil tape.

Comment: JDługosz, This is an A/C air handler (blower unit). The cooling coil is inside and this is where the condensation occurs. That is a condensate drain.

Comment: I would peel up that insulation and check that you actually have a metal panel under it. If you don't someone, lost the panel, and made a leaky panel out of bubble wrap..

Comment: @SpeedyPetey If you are a duck, "speed tape" is the correct stuff to use.  *It's for aircraft.*

Comment: The copper tubing carries refrigerant to and from the evaporator coil inside the insulated section. The smaller line is the warm liquid refrigerant going into the evaporator (cooling) coil inside and the larger line is gaseous refrigerant going outside back to the condensing unit. When the compressor in the outside unit is running the larger line should be cold.  To test it, I would just press on it with your hand to see if there is a metal panel underneath.  Where is this property located?

Comment: @Jim Stewart, property is in central New Jersey. I pressed on the foil part, there doesn't seem to be a flat surface underneath, I can feel there's several circular objects protruding underneath. Also I have double AC units for the house (3600sqft), and the AC is still quite weak, in 90F+ degree days, I can't bring the house colder than 80F, the AC blows tiny amount of air into the house.

Comment: Well your a/c is not working properly then. You should get a service call from an a/c service company. If you have two separate a/c "zones", are both of them not cooling? Contact a well regarded a/c service company. You do not have a DIY project in front of you.